# How precise were the Temples' directions (East/North)

Tags: beis-hamikdash, science, astronomy

Calculating the true astronomical North/South is very simple - find the longest way and cast a shadow.

Are there sources on how *precise* those directions in the Temples were? Are there special Jewish calculations? Is there a tradition of pointing to a certain landmark (a point on Mt. Olives) or aligning with the stars?

(for [comparison](https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn174-pyramid-precision/), "*The [Egyptian pyramids] tombs are aligned north-south with an accuracy of up to 0.05 degrees.*")

Comment: There are walls on the Temple mount visible to satellites that are uncannily aligned with the cardinal directions. Can't prove anything without archaeology of course.

Answer (score 4):

[Yerushalmi Eruvin 33a](https://www.sefaria.org/Jerusalem_Talmud_Eruvin.33a.1):

> כמה יגעו נביאים הראשונים לעשות שער המזרחי שתהא החמה מצמצמת בו באחד בתקופת טבת ובאחד בתקופת תמוז.
>
> How much effort the early prophets put in to make the eastern gate [of the Har Habayis] such that the sun would shine exactly through it on the first day of the winter season and the first day of the summer season.

See also [Bavli Eruvin 56a](https://www.sefaria.org/Eruvin.56a?lang=he), that similar methods can be used when measuring the techum of a city.

Comment: Great! 2. מצמצמת=shine? מצמצמת what, its rays? a very strange use for this word. Wait, טבת and תמוז? That's summer and winter: תקופת ניסן: 7/8 באפריל, and תקופת תמוז: 7/8 ביולי and תקופת תשרי: 7 באוקטובר and תקופת טבת: 6/7 בינואר, Why?

Comment: @AlBerko מצמצמת would mean to fit exactly (no overlap on either side). תקופת טבת and תקופת ניסן (according to Shmuel's calculation) nowadays are on those dates, but back then they were better aligned with the actual astronomical dates.

Comment: Do you mean like מצטמצמת?

Comment: But that seems impossible, it has to be in the same position, i,g, 21/3 and 21/9

Comment: @AlBerko מצטמצמת would be reflexive (fits itself exactly); מצמצמת is transitive (makes something else - its light - fit exactly). Not sure what you mean with your second comment, but the neviim weren't necessarily using approximations such as Shmuel's tekufah - they might have used more precise calculations, similar to Rambam in Hilchos Kiddush Hachodesh.

Comment: Har HaBayis is at 31 degrees north, meaning that the sun will rise at 8 degrees south of due east on the summer solstice but 54 degrees south of due east on the winter solstice (on average - there’s some variation from year to year). Most likely these gates faced the average of these two positions to most effectively get sunlight at both of them; this would mean that it faced ~31 degrees south of due east.

Comment: @DonielF interesting, please continue, shouldn't it be on 3/21 and 9/21?

Comment: @AlBerko Those are the spring and fall equinoxes, where it would be 31 degrees south of due east, which would be straight ahead if the doors are facing as I theorized. As an aside, a Rebbe of mine theorizes that north in Tanach isn’t due north, based on Bavel being described as north of Eretz Yisrael. If you rotate about 31 degrees clockwise, that would solve that issue as well.

Comment: @DonielF and how it relates to תקופות?

Comment: @AlBerko Well, on the summer solstice the sun is directly overhead (or due east at sunrise) at 23 degrees north; as this is 8 degrees *further* north, the sun will appear 8 degrees further south in the sky. Conversely on the winter solstice the sun is directly overhead (or due east at sunrise) at 23 degrees south, or 54 degrees south of Har HaBayis.

Comment: @DonielF if it says "באחד בתקופת טבת ובאחד בתקופת תמוז." that would be at winter (12/26) and summer (6/26) and that's impossible https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%A2_%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%AA#תקופת_רב_אדא

Comment: @AlBerko Your link’s broken.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95034/discussion-between-al-berko-and-donielf).

Comment: @DonielF and Meir It appears, from the second sight, I don't understand what this statement says. I understand the first part - that the placement was very exact, but since the sun shines through the Eastern gate all year long what makes it special?